# Codeblocks required files

Tags: c++, codeblocks, sdl-2

I'm learning to use the Codeblocks editor and I would like to setup a SDL2 project. My question is about the necessary files in the SDL2 package.

In the bin directory there is:

sdl-config

In the lib directory there is:

directories -

cmake and pkgconfig

In the share directory there is:

aclocal

I deleted these files, but my experience with SDL2 and C++ is almost at a beginner level. My understanding is, that these support files are for various command line tools used for compilation. For example I know what pkg-config is and I searched somewhat for the other file types. Is it ok to delete these files since I am using Codeblocks, or will Codeblocks possibly require any of these in some unexpected way at a later time? that I might not have considered. As far as I know, Codeblocks makes full use of it's wizards and it's project handling is separate from these other tools. I basically like to set everything up as an Empty Project. I have no compilation issues or errors, but I wanted the opinion of someone more experienced on this.

Comment: Essentially you only need the `.a` files, the headers, and the `.dll`. You can delete the rest. But I'd suggest to set up the project manually, instead of relying on CB project templates.

Comment: I know that maybe I'm little late, but take a look at this tutorial here: https://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/01_hello_SDL/windows/codeblocks/index.php